# How to stop a loop on slot - Watson Conversation tooling

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

I have been using Watson Conversation for quite some time. Recently, with the news features, I started using the slot option. I would like to know if it is possible to stop a loop with a counter directly on the tooling. I can stop the loop using a diferent condition on manage handlers, but not with a counter.
Anyone knows how to do that on the the tooling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are in the right area. You use the handlers.

1. Create a context variable called `counter` and set it to a value of `1`. The reason for 1 is that setting it to 0 can make it invisible. Do this in the welcome part.

2. Create your slot. For the example, I am setting the condition as `input.text == "go"`.

3. Set up your slots as normal. Again for the example, I look for `$person` and `$date` (@sys-person and @sys-date)

4. In the handler for the first response on "If answer to any prompt is not found and:" set the JSON to:

```
{
  "conditions": "$counter > 3",
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "You have gotten the question wrong too many times."
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  },
  "context": {
    "date": "cancel",
    "person": "cancel",
    "counter": 99
  }
}
```

This will activate if the handler is hit 3 times. It will set `counter` to `99` (see later), set the wanted context variables to `"cancel"` so as to exit the slot.

5. The second response in the handler, set it to this JSON.

```
{
  "output": {},
  "context": {
    "counter": "<? $counter = $counter + 1 ?>"
  }
}
```

This is your increment for `counter`.

6. Back to the main part of the slot. In the "Then respond with:", set the condition to:

```
$date != "cancel" or $person != "cancel"
```

and set the response to display your values. At this point it should work. However if you try to enter the slot again it will fail. So lets build a handler for that.

7. Create a child node under your slot. Set your slot to "finally jump to" the condition block.

8. In your child node, set the condition to: `$counter == 99`. For your JSON response put in the following:

```
{
  "context": {
    "counter": 1,
    "date": null,
    "person": null
  },
  "output": {}
}
```

This resets the counter, and removes the slot variables. This allows you to re-enter the slot.

Here is an example conversation workspace: https://pastebin.com/caA2gb5u

---

To follow on from this (not in the example). You can use the individual slot handlers for each context variable to reset the counter in the same way.